# TypeScript Not Autogenerating JS Maps

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Running VS Code 1.28.2

When I go to generate a build from my extension's `extension.ts` file, source map files for my `.ts` files are not being automatically generated in my project structure's `out` folder

Only the maps generated from another machine are in the project.

.vscode/launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension Tests",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
                "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
        }
    ]
}
```

.vscode/tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch",
            "isBackground": true,
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

./tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        ".vscode-test"
    ]
}
```

Even if I rename ./out to something else, a new out folder is never created. I'm not sure what I'm missing here when trying to debug. Any point in the right direction appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Seems like just running `tsc -w` in a terminal the root of my `tsconfig.json` gives me what I need. Based on the settings it looked like that would happen automatically